# Why do I need to subscribe user to topic in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement chat. For example user A , B, C... 
Each user can send message to each other it is standard like `whatsup`...

And according to [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) , when one user send message to another ,I have to subscribe them to one topic.

For example user A send message to user B, server create a topic `testTopicName` and subscribe them to this topic with this line of code

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(testTopicName);
```

but question is why i need subscribe users to topic if i can do next:

Send notification from server to user and with name or uniq Id of topic
User open this new topic by this uniq Id of topic that was retrived from server

This is code from documentation

```
 mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage,
            MessageViewHolder>(
            FriendlyMessage.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            MessageViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(testTopicName)) {
```

Could you explain what is advantage to use subscribe if otherwise we anyway need to represent user list of messages...

Feel free to ask if i explain my point of view not clearly enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to target messages sent with Firebase Cloud Messaging. From the [documentation, you can send to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message):

- Topic name
- Device registration token
- Device group name

In the article I decided to associate each user with a topic. This has the following advantages:

- the app doesn't have to [deal with registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register). If you use these tokens, you'll have to store them somewhere, provide lookup for them, etc. All definitely possible, but using topics made the article a lot shorter.
- if the same user has the chat app on multiple devices, they will receive the notification on each device

And these disadvantages:

- each user needs to have a unique username.
- messages are not private (see [Creating Firebase topic for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243552/creating-firebase-topic-for-each-user))

In the chat app a user already has a unique nick name, so this provides a simple user-visible value to map to the topics. If you, Veener and me are in a chat, there will be three topics: `/topics/user_aleksey`, `/topics/user_veener` and `/topics/user_puf`. And whenever you or Veener mentions me in a chat, the notifications will be pushed to `/topics/user_puf`.

There are many ways to map to topics. Which way is best depends on your app.

Comment: I am going to finish with this implementation and would like you to comfirm my finilly understanding... User A send message to user B. message saving in FCM DB and immediatly server script catch this message, reading recipents and sending him notification with name of topic. And user B connecting to this topic, right? Last question is - this topic name have to be uniq , is there some out of box approach to do it?

Comment: You seem to think that topics are something more magical than they are. It is just a publish/subscribe model. If you publish a notification to a topic, then all subscribers to that topic get the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Publish/subscribe is useful if you have a lot of clients.  Let's say you have a weather app and wanted to push a weather warning like a tornado to everyone who lived in a specific city.  You could publish a message once to a topic for that city (which would get delivered to everyone who is subscribing to that city) or you could send out thousand of messages to every person who lives in that city looping though all users and sending many individual messages.  Which one seems easier to implement and deliver?

Comment: ok, thanks! i get your point of view. But if i understand you correctly, if i need implement chat and send message from one exact user to another i have not to use subscribing concept, right?

Comment: Correct.  You are not required to use publish/subscribe for a peer to peer message.

Comment: Have you ever try appy firebase? Because as far as i understand, one user create a topic and another user have ability to read and write posts to this exsiting topic if he know name(uniq Id)... If SMO else will know name of topic he also can read/write and firebase will immidiatly synhronice it between all how know name of topic. And doesn't matter if it will be chat whit 2 users or weather warning with 1000 subscribers... Differens only in permissions you can be like admin and only you will post or other side all users will have permission to write and it will look like chat, right?