# Creating Firebase topic for each user

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a design approach which is creating a topic for each registered user.

1. Creating a new user
2. Save it to our database with a generated token
3. Subscribe to `/topics/{user-token}` when user login on android or
   ios device.

So if user have more than one device and if we want to send a user specific notification, we just send it to `/topics/{user-token}` so it received by all devices.

We've not encountered any problem with a few users yet, but is that ok for Firebase limitations and is it a good approach?

Comment: Sounds good. Why you give a name "user-token" for uid or userId, like Google evangelist do?

Comment: If the use-case is for a single user with multiple devices, why not use [Device Group Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)?

Comment: @AL. you're right, i missed it, but we've to manage group list if we use it, like if somebody logout from android device, i've sent a request to my server, remove it's  registration_id etc. But if I use `topic`, I just unsubscribe on client side. I would choose topic if it's ok for firebase. But thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Whichever works with less hassle is OK. Cheers! :)

Comment: Topics are PUBLIC. Any user (even from a different app) can subscribe to /topics/{user-token} and receive those messages. If this is ok for your app then you are good. But remember that messages sent to topics are basically public.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini, that's actually a little bit not ok for me :(, but are you sure about that `"Any user (even from a different app) can subscribe to /topics/{user-token}`"? Beacuse I have used so many times /topics/user or /topics/general so if topics are public, I'm sure that there might be a conflict.

Comment: I am sure. You didn't run into conflicts because in each app you used a different firebase-projects / google-services.json.  But another developer can download your app, copy that file, and then subscribe to receive messages from your topics.

Comment: @DiegoGiorgini user-token is guid so it wouldn't be a problem if another developers can't get a list of topics?

Comment: Correct. But if another dev can find it you are screwed because you cannot change guid and you would not even know that someone else is receiving a copy of your messages. Send to a specific token is more secure. You can choose your level of security based on your needs.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(I am moving my comments into an answer)

**Most of the times creating an FCM TOPIC per user is NOT a good idea.**

> Messages sent to an FCM TOPICS are public.    Any user (even from a
>   different app) can subscribe to /topics/{user-name} and receive those
>   messages.

**Example:**
Another developer can copy the google-services.json file from your apk.
Then he can subscribe to any topic.
To intercept your user messages the attacker still need to guess the {user-name} or any other identifier you are using. But if you assume this can happen then the issue is big because you would never know if someone is receiving a copy of your messages, and you usually never change {user-name}.

This is not a security issue of FCM. This is part of the topic API design.
If you need secure messages you can send them directly to the device token.

If you still want to do one topic per user, please pay attention to not send sensitive data, or data that should not be intercepted by third parties.

Comment: please explain **If you need secure messages you can send them directly to the device token.**

Comment: I have the same issue. How do I handle that instead of topics? Save all devices tokens in a collection and send notification one by one?