# FCM device groups vs topics

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an iOS app that sends notifications to individual groups of users. Number of users per group will most likely be in the order of 1-7, but can exceed that and while the app generally doesn't set a limit, I hardly see it exceeding 20.

Currently I've set it up with the topics approach and it works like it should. I understand this approach is optimized for throughput rather than latency, as opposed to device groups.

Nearing completion of my app, I'm considering to change to device groups. However, I don't see many advantages, especially considering the substantial complexity that comes along with it.

Notifications at the moment is fast enough. As long as delivery time doesn't suddenly increase by a lot, it's perfectly fine at the moment.

**How secure are topics compared with device groups?**

The app does allow the user to use more than one device, but I don't see that happening often - realistically quite seldom. However if that were to happen, device groups would handle it better. Still, I think it's an acceptable compromise to stick with topics.

For device groups to work, I have to create a new collection server-side to manage device registration tokens and their updates, pairing with my existing data structure and implementing several http requests. I also need to query for the notification_key every time I want to send a notification, instead of sending it to the more obvious id I now use for topics.

I've read through other questions on SO, but wanted to get some fresh thoughts on this. My opinion is to stay with topics unless convinced otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I'm using both of these delivery methods and yes, topics are far easier to manage but that comes at a cost of security. If your groups are public in nature then you should be fine with topics. If they're meant to handle more sensitive/private information you should probably go with device groups / individual tokens. Reason being, topics are more public facing and anyone can listen in on them, *[even devices not on your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291098/9910719).*